# How to keep AST for feature access?

Tags: compiler, parsing

Consider such code (let's say it is C++)

```
Foo::Bar.get().X
```

How one should keep the AST for this -- as "tree" with root at left `Foo(Bar(get(X))`, or with root at right `(((Foo)Bar)get)X`? Or maybe as a flat structure (list)?

The first one seems more convenient when resolving names, the second when working with it as expression.

*I set tag `parsing` but I am asking from semantic analysis POV really (there is no such tag).*

Comment: The order depends on the order of operations of the expression. It's not really an AST otherwise...

Comment: @Telastyn, the expression is as I gave you above, so the order will be...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example gets the attribute X of the result of calling method bar() on the result of getting static member Bar of the result of evaluating the name Foo. As a tree:

```
GetAttribute
+-CallMethod
| +-GetStaticMember
| | +-Foo
| | +-Bar
| +-bar
| +-[] // parameters
+-X
```